# KeyIntersection fails (?) when an association is empty

Tags: bugs, core-language, associations

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0. Fixed in 10.4.0**

I think I found a bug in `KeyIntersection` (Mma 10.2).  To illustrate, input the following:

```
KeyIntersection[{Association[], Association[]}]
```

This returns `KeyIntersection[{<||>, <||>}]` instead of `{<||>, <||>}`.  Only one of the inputted associations need be empty to create this problem.

Am I right that this is a bug?  If so, is it fixed in 10.3?

Comment: The output is the same in 10.3

Comment: I interpret the up votes as agreement that this is a bug.  Therefore I have reported it as such.

Comment: Keep us informed about the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was still broken in version 10.3.1, but is fixed from version 10.4.0 onward (at least up to version 11).

```
$Version
(* "10.4.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (February 26, 2016)" *)

KeyIntersection[{Association[], Association[]}]
(* {<||>, <||>} *)
```